# Vapor - Trying to manually set up starter project

Tags: swift, vapor

I just downloaded Xcode 8 and I tried to setup Vapor Test Project manually so followed up this tutorial:

https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/manual.html

But at the time I perform `swift build` on the terminal I keep receiving this error:

> Compile Swift Module 'Hello' (1 sources)
>
> /Users/davidvpe/Desktop/Hello/Sources/main.swift:9:1:
>
> error: value of type 'Droplet' has no member 'run'
>
> drop.run()
>
> ^~~~ ~~~
>
> :0:
> error: build had 1 command failures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Vapor guys didn't update the docs in vapor.codes.

This is what should be in Package.swift

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Hello",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
    ]
)
```

Comment: yeah, I just saw it